# Format an integer given an integer and the number of digits to use

Tags: c#

Given

```
int myNumber=6
int myDigits=4
```

how do I asssign

```
string myString = "0006"
```

I asssume it would use `string.Format()`

Comment: please show what you have tried and why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
string myString = 6.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: if the number is 10 then won't pad left result in a 5 digit number?

Comment: @SmileyFtW 10 will get you `0010`. "4" is total number of characters in the result

Comment: Perfect... thank you

Comment: the result was for a return string and looks like this and appears to do what I need `return _seqnumber.ToString().PadLeft(_seqNumDigits,'0')`

Comment: @SmileyFtW Glad it worked for you. The reason whey they downvoted is because you have not done your research. Well, happens. This also works `10.ToString("D4")`

Comment: Well, I had done *some* homework I found `Format` and `PadLeft`. I am just now trying to learn C# coming from VBA. I googled and what I found seemed to indicate `PadLeft` was not what I wanted even though it turned out to be exactly what I needed. I know how to do a quick test in VBA, but don't have that skill in C# just yet. Thank you for the answer. I upvoted your solution as it was indeed the answer.

Comment: No problem. If this answers, you should also accept this answer. Another way to do - old programmer way - if you have max 5 chars, and you can have 1 to 5 initial chars, just concatenate `"0000" + val`. Then substring 5 last chars. But .net makes it all easy for you. All this is already built-in